# _remote.repositories prevents maven from resolving remote parent

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus, maven-dependency-plugin

I have my company parent pom in `releases` repository on a company Nexus instance.

I have mirror settings of `<mirrorOf>external:*,!central</mirrorOf>`, I don't want to proxy central since our Nexus is a bit slow.

When I have a maven project, with parent set like:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.acme.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>2</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

and the `parent-pom` project is not available in local repository the build will fail -- this is as expected so far.

However if I download the `parent-pom` using `dependency:get` goal, the pom file gets downloaded to local repository. However when I try to build the project it fails with:

```
 [exec] [ERROR]   The project com.acme:test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/home/acme/pom.xml) has 1 error
 [exec] [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.acme.maven:parent-pom:pom:2 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 13 -> [Help 2]
```

Now if I remove the `_remote.repositories` file (and only that file) from `.m2/repository/com/acme/maven/parent-pom/2/` the build will succeed.

I have some kind of a workaround, but **manually removing internal files from maven repository doesn't sound like a good idea. How can avoid it?**
Also I have no idea why is this happening, some explanation will be much appreciated.

Other approaches:

- maven-ant tasks `dependencies` task *works* (`_remote.repositories` file doesn't appear at all)
- trying to build with `-U`
- using `dependency:copy` *fails*
- using `dependency:list` on a `pom.xml` having the `parent-pom` as dependency also *fails*

---

`_remote.repositories` content:

```
#NOTE: This is an Aether internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Mon Sep 14 19:59:41 CEST 2015
parent-pom-2.pom>internal-repo=
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is [here](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Cannot-find-parent-POM-but-it-s-there-td5776845.html):

> Maven 3.0+ enforces that downloaded artifacts were resolved from a
>   repository url/id that matches an url available for the current
>   session.

..

> IIRC there is a CLI option that you can enabled in Maven 3.1.1 that
>   tells Maven "I know what I am doing and don't make that check this
>   time" i.e.
>   --legacy-local-repository

Indeed adding `--legacy-local-repository` to the `dependency:get` invocation makes it *not* produce the `_remote.repositories`, and the `parent-pom` can be resolved.

Ant's `dependencies` task behaviour can, I think, be explained by it using Maven 2 code.