# Isolate maven jar dependencies that are unavailable from maven central

Tags: docker, maven

I am attempting to refactor a maven build process, and I am trying to populate a local maven repository to help with this refactor.

My build depends on obsolete versions of jar files that exist only in a maven repo on my network (not in maven central). Example: `org.foo:example:1.7:jar`

I have been attempting to run my maven build in a docker image image with the hope that I could identify all of the obsolete components being pulled from my maven repository.

My goal is to explicitly pull down dependencies from my maven repo and then build the application using only maven central as an external repository.

I have a docker file to run the build

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8 as build

WORKDIR /build

# This pom.xml file only references maven central.
COPY pom.xml .

# Explicitly download artifacts into /root/.m2/...

RUN mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.foo:example:1.7.jar \
  -DrepoUrl=https://my.maven.repo

# Run the build making use of the dependencies loaded into the local repo
RUN mvn install
```

Unfortunately, I see an error: `could not resolve dependencies for project ... The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.foo:example:jar:1.7`.

I presume there might be some metadata in my local org.foo:example:1.7:pom that has an awareness of its origin repository.  I had hoped I could satisfy this dependency by pulling it into my local repository.

I also attempted to add the following flag

```
RUN mvn install --no-snapshot-updates
```

Comment: Without the full error message / output it's impossible to even guess...

Comment: This question may help my investigation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571400/remote-repositories-prevents-maven-from-resolving-remote-parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I discovered that the downloads in my .m2/repository contained files named `_remote.repositories`.

### Solution: set `-Dmaven.legacyLocalRepo=true` when running dependency:get

With this flag, the `_remote.repositories` files are not created.

```
RUN mvn dependency:get -Dmaven.legacyLocalRepo=true \
  -Dartifact=org.foo:example:1.7.jar \
  -DrepoUrl=https://my.maven.repo
```

This question helped to provide a solution: [_remote.repositories prevents maven from resolving remote parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571400/remote-repositories-prevents-maven-from-resolving-remote-parent)